# Comparing two excelsheets for uncommon cells based on common 'id' field(Column C)

Tags: vba, excel

So I have two worksheets.  The first one is "Upsert" and the Second is "Compare".

I will be doing this comparison weekly so row count will differ every time aka number of projects to compare will be different.

Both of these worksheets have a Column C with a project ID (unique).  What i want to happen is for the macro to find a project ID in the "Upsert" spreadsheet column C and if it finds that same project ID in Column C of the "Compare" spreadsheet, to then compare the whole rows to make sure everything matches the "Compare" spreadsheet (columns on both sheets are in the same order so hope that helps).  If any cell in that row we are comparing does not match, highlight yellow in the "Upsert" spreadsheet.  There are 38 columns in each worksheet.

NOT A HUGE PRIORITY AS ABOVE BUT IF ALSO POSSIBLE:
If there are project IDs in the "upsert" spreadsheet that are not found in the "compare" spreadsheet, highlight those.  Also if there are project ids found in the "compare" spreadsheet that are not found in the "upsert" spreadsheet, highlight in the "compare" spreadsheet.

Please let me know if there are questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Paste code in a `Module` and should work as is.

---

If a **Project ID** exists on `Upsert` and NOT on `Compare`: Project ID will highlight red on `Upsert`

If a **Project ID** exists on both sheets, 38 columns will be compared (starting with A and moving outward). If the columns do not match, the cell in question will highlight yellow on `Upsert`. If your column span increases, you will need to adjust the `38` in the `For i` loop.

---

I did not include your last ask (if it exists on `Compare` and not on `Upsert` highlight yellow on `Compare`). You should be able to figure that out using below code and the internets.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()

Dim Upsert As Worksheet: Set Upsert = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Upsert")
Dim Compare As Worksheet: Set Compare = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare")

Dim ProjectIDs As Range: Set ProjectIDs = Upsert.Range("K2:K" & Upsert.Range("K" & Upsert.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = Compare.Range("K:K")
Dim Project As Range, Found As Range, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Project In ProjectIDs
        Set Found = SearchRange.Find(Project, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not Found Is Nothing Then           'If Project ID is found
                For i = 1 To 38                    'Compare Columns
                    If Upsert.Cells(Project.Row, i).Value2 <> Compare.Cells(Found.Row, i).Value2 Then
                        Upsert.Cells(Project.Row, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    End If
                Next i                             'Next Column Comparison
            Else                                   'If a project ID is not found
                Project.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
    Next Project
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Please show an attempt next time", vbCritical

End Sub
```

**Run-time:** less than a second for 2,000 rows

This could probably be sped up by loading the column values in an array and do array by array comparison (by item). I don't know how many rows you expect to have which will determine the speed of this ultimately. If this is slow for you, I would pursue an array comparison rather a cell by cell comparison, which is what I have provided.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering: I realized it is column K instead of C :( .  Can I simply use K where you have C?

Comment: I also wanted to clarify your For i = 1 to 34.  What is the 34 for?  Lastly, if my column count changes from 38 is that ok? Column K (see comment above) will not change but i may add more columns later on to compare.... @urdearboy

Comment: Hey @urdearboy so the column i need to use is k (column #11).  I need it to say for example, project id 1440 in K (both worksheets).  If 1440 is found in both sheets in column K (could be different rows), then compare the whole row (columns A (1) though column #38. Highlight differences on upsert :) Thank you!!!!!

Comment: I cant thank you enough!!! I've been wracking my brain on this for so long and you made it so easy!!!!  Just to confirm if ever down the road like in 6 months i need to compare more columns, I would just expand the 38 in the code?  Also if for whatever reason column K needed to be changed to say J (I doubt it but just in case) would i just edit where the "K" is at in the code? @urdearboy

Comment: Yup. it is comparing the first 38 columns (which equates to columns `A` to `AL`). If you extend this to 2 more columns, you will change 38 to 40.

Comment: Also if for whatever reason column K needed to be changed to say J (I doubt it but just in case) would i just edit where the "K" is at in the code? @urdearboy

Comment: Yup. Make sure you get all instances of `K` though. I believe the code has 5 instances.